# Tooltip on ResponsiveSunburst is not showing

Tags: reactjs, nivo-react

I'm using `nivo/sunburst` to show a tooltip as it shows in the example but si not showing anyhting when doing onHover the sunburst chart

```
    <ResponsiveSunburst
      data={data}
      id="name"
      margin={{ right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, top: 10 }}
      value="loc"
      borderColor={{ from: 'data.color' }}
      arcLabelsRadiusOffset={0}
      arcLabelsTextColor={{ from: 'data.color' }}
      colors={{ datum: 'data.color' }}
      animate
      tooltip={() => <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'black' }}>as</div>}
    />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What version of `@nivo/core` and `@nivo/sunburst` are you using? There was a bug fix in [version 0.80.0](https://github.com/plouc/nivo/releases/tag/v0.80.0) to fix tooltips on Pie and I believe it also worked for Sunburst. I personally had 0.78.0 and Sunburst tooltips were not working for me until I updated.